# Elements inside ItemsControl don't update, but inside ListBox they do

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, itemscontrol

(Editing the whole post, since you guys think there is some code magic going on)

## Introduction

I've got an *Observable Collection* which should be visualized in a list

For that purpose I want to use an *ItemsControl*, but the list elements do not update (they are empty or show fallback values I defined)

when using a *ListBox instead it works as expected*, but then I've got the list item selection which I don't want.

### TL;DR; Problem

ItemsControl does not show the correct values, but a ListBox does.

## Code to reproduce

To reproduce the problem, I made a new WPF project, as simple as possible to show the problem, this is the **complete code of my minimal example**

I have a custom UserControl mostly showing some text, in this case an address, which (currently) is only set in the constructor:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly string _address;

        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public MyUserControl(string address)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _address = address;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Address));
        }

        public string Address => _address;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

this is the XAML code for the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.MyUserControl"
             <!-- snip namespaces --> 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.6">
        <Border.Style> <!-- snip --> </Border.Style>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Padding="2" Content="Address:"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Padding="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding Path=Address, FallbackValue=00000000000000000000000000000}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The XAML of the main window, now renders two lists one ItemsControl and one ListBox using the same binding and whatsoever

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
       <!-- snip namespaces -->
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="FeeKeyListView" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="200">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:MyUserControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="200">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:MyUserControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

last but not least the MainWindow class, where the Observable list is contained:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public ObservableCollection<MyUserControl> MyList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyUserControl>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyList.Clear();
            MyList.Add(new MyUserControl("my address1"));
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting window shows, that the values are correctly bound in the ListBox but not in the ItemsControl

**The desired behavior** would be, that the ItemsControl shows 'my address1' like the ListBox does.

[image]

Comment: The elements in the XAML of MyUserControl bind directly to MyClass properties? And MyUserControl does not accidentially set its own DataContext?

Comment: I simplified the binding structure a bit. Point is: it works with ListBox as expected but not with ItemsControl (both would use the same template and binding code)

Comment: Without any more details, we won't be able to tell what's going on. An ItemTemplate should usually work identical in a ListBox and an ItemsControl.

Comment: But the ItemsSource should also work identically, so the binding should not be the point, shouldn't it? (updating more informations in the original post)

Comment: A listbox is an itemscontrol, with some added functionality. Template either of their items and they work the same. Because they are essentially the same thing. Your problem is therefore not inherent to itemscontrol vs listbox. It's in some other detail of your usage. In code you've not shown us.

Comment: @Andy I added a minimal reproducable example for you, including full code in the comment. Hopefully you can help me now, since the problem drives me a bit crazy

Comment: Your problem is that you are binding to a list of controls. `MyList` contains instances of `MyUserControl`. Each item is replaced with a new and blank `MyUserControl` instance, which is generated by applying the `DataTemplate` to each item. Therefore the behavior of `ItemsControl` is the expected behavior. Why or if `ListBox` simply omits the `DataTemplate` for some reason I haven't checked as I didn't run your example.

Comment: The only difference (regarding the item container) between `ItemsControl` and any more specialized sub type is that `ItemsControl` uses a plain `ContentPresenter` as item container and not a `ContentControl` like `ListBoxItem` as e.g. `ListBox` does. The templates are applied by the virtual `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` method, which usually invokes the base implementation provided by `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Anyway, to solve your problem you should remove the `DataTemplate`. It is fairly redundant, since it only contains a `MyUserControl` while the items are already of type `MyUserControl`. Otherwise, if you want to use this templates for what reason ever, you must at least bind the properties of the new `MyUserControl` instance to the instance of the `DataContext`.

Comment: You usually don't use `DataTemplate` to apply it on controls. The template is meant to describe the visual appearance of data objects. If you had a e.g. `Connection` data type which exposes a `Address` property, you could generate a collection of `Connection` items and bind it to a `ItemsControl`. Now by defining a `DataTemplate` you can make each data item to be rendered as e.g. `MyUserControl`, where `MyUserControl.Address` would bind to `Connection.Address`. See [Microsoft Docs: Data Templating Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Also you don't have to call `Clear()` on an instantiated empty collection. `MyList.Clear();` is redundant.

Comment: The `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Address));` call in the constructor is also without effect and can be removed. Once the control or binding target is loaded, it will automatically execute every existing binding to a source property e.g., `Address` in order to initialize itself.

Comment: @BionicCode thanks for your insight and explanation! the problem was solved when moving the data to a separate ViewModel class. It really seems that ListBox and ItemsControl behave differently when using UserControls as DataContext. 
Simply Removing DataTemplate is not possible though, since ItemTemplate must not be empty.
For the redundancies: In my original code the list is not filled in the constructor, and those are leftovers.thanks anyways.

Comment: when @Clemens and the others who voted for closing reopen the issue I'd be glad to accept an answer and mark this as solved.

Comment: You can define a `ItemsControl` without specifying the `ItemsTemplate`. Just don't set the property i.e. remove it completely from your markup.

Comment: But to move the data into a model class is the cleaner solution. This way you don't have to explicitly create user controls in code-behind. This is then accomplished by the XAML engine automatically.

Comment: I tried removing ItemsTemplate alltogether but it had the same result. atleast IIRC.
The question is not closed anymore, if you create an Answer i'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different behavior results from the different implementations of the [`IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.isitemitsowncontaineroverride?view=netcore-3.1) method, in [ItemsControl](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,25566aa6db31bf29)

```
protected virtual bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    return (item is UIElement);
}
```

and in [ListBox](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ListBox.cs,705ce5aa9d7130a0)

```
protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    return (item is ListBoxItem);
}
```

When the method returns true for an item from the `Items` or `ItemsSource` collection - which it does in ItemsControl for your UserControls - no item container is generated and hence no ItemTemplate is applied.

However, you would usually not assign a collection of UIElements to the ItemsSource property, but instead a collection of view model items - to which the elements in the ItemTemplate bind their properties.